# How to enable/disable exception handling for a class

Tags: php, oop, error-handling, exception

I have a class that handles errors with exceptions, like

```
class fooException extends Exception{}

class foo {

  public function bar($x){
    if(!$x){
        throw new fooException ("x can not be false value");
     }
  }

}
```

Now, what I am trying to do, is allow user of the class to make choices whether an exception should be thrown, or not just like the PDO class.

```
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
```

So, I was to give flexibility to the class not to throw exceptions all the time.

Comment: I think you’d need to wrap your actual `throw new fooException` line of code into an `if` statement then, resp. add another condition to your existing one – something like `if(!$x && THROW_EXCEPTIONS){ …`, where `THROW_EXCEPTIONS` is a constant set to true or false.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You can set for example a static variable and check for that before you decide to throw an exception.

Comment: There is no problem @jeroen I know you can do anything with if/else but I was wandering if there was another way, as I am unfamiliar with how the exception class works beyond the basics.

Comment: @CBroe that seems like a nice idea. I would have to define a constant after a namespace, then set it to `false` by default, then do if/else to check before throwing an exception.

Comment: _“as I am unfamiliar with how the exception class works beyond the basics”_ – that is not the point here; _throwing_ the exception happens “outside” of that class, and that is what you want to prevent here in the first place. The internal workings of the exception class have nothing to do with this, simply for the fact that when that class is invoked, it is “too late” already. To avoid getting hit by the car you don’t need to know how the combustion engine works – you need to get your a$$ off the road ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the Exception in a better way

```
class MyException extends Exception 
{
    static public $enable = true;
    public function __construct($message = null, $code = 0)
    {       
        if (self::$enable) {
            parent::__construct($message, $code);
        }
    }

}
```

the you could call

```
throw new MyException("x can not be false value");
MyException::enable = false; //for disable
```

*Note this is really very basic implementation* and you have the problem to handle the false state in some way.

Another better solution is to use an ExceptionHandler

```
class ExceptionHanlder
{
    static public $enable = true;
    function __construct($message = null,$code = null) {
        if (self::$enable) {
            throw new Exception($message,$code);
        }
    }

}
ExceptionHandler::$enable = false;
new ExceptionHandler('test');
```

Comment: Something like this should do it although I am not sure what the consequences of throwing an exception and not calling the parent constructor are. I'd probably handle it in the `foo` class myself to avoid having to throw an exception at all.

Comment: totally agree, it's necessary to handle the other parts, I edit again the code

Comment: error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
       } catch (...) {